# mount -a return an error

Tags: mount

I am trying to mount a folder from `10.100.XXX.XXX` on my build client at the path: `/home/projects/Polyspace_Server`. I modified my `/etc/fstab` with (I have already tried this with another project linux machine and it works):

```
10.100.XXX.XXX:/opt/Polyspace_Server/R2021b /home/projects/Polyspace_Server nfs defaults 0 0
```

but when I try to do `mount -a`, I get:

```
$ sudo mount -a sudo: unable to resolve host XXXXX: Connection timed out
 mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
 10.100.XXX.XXX:/opt/Polyspace_Server/R2021b,
        missing codepage or helper program, or other error
        (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
        need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
 
        In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
        dmesg | tail or so.
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you `ping XXXX` from the machine where you want to mount? The error is telling you it couldn't resolve the hostname/IP.

Comment: Are you using a host name or IP address? In the fstab there is an IP address but the error suggests a host name. If it's suppose to be an IP address then there might be a typo in the fstab.

Comment: ... it actually looks like the `unable to resolve host` error is from `sudo`, rather than from `mount` (it might be clearer if the OP had not obfuscated the addresses)

Comment: You can try ```showmount -e 10.100.xxx.xxx``` to check for nfs mount if it is not showing anything then there might be problem with firewall.